# Storing a Lookup Table in VBA Function

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to create a function that will automatically change the iso country codes to the country name. For example, a function that will take a string "FRA" as an input and return "France" as an output. To me that means I will have to store static lookup tables in a VBA module. Is this possible? What functionality should I use to make the change?

Comment: you can just create an array in your vba module and search it

Comment: Honestly, I would create a separate (possibly hidden) worksheet to store the country code/replacement values. Then use a VBA method that would build a Dictionary on demand when values on any other worksheet need to be examined and (possibly) replaced. If you set it up this way, then you can change your ISO/replacement data at any time and you'll not have to change the underlying VBA code at all.